# UIStackView in UITableView Jerk while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistackview

I have looked at a number of solutions related to this issue but still couldn't get it working right.

I have a `UITableView`, that contains a number of `UITableViewCells`. In one of the `UITableViewCell`, there is a `UIStackView` which further contains multiple `UIStackViews` that is determined dynamically.

i.e., hierarchy is something like:

**`UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UIStackView -> UIStackView(multiple)`**

Now, when I scroll the `UITableView`, it gives a jerky experience. There are no ambiguous `AutoLayout constraints`.

[image]

Comment: All you are doing is scrolling the table? No code running except generating the next row(s) in the table? If so, look at what's generating the next cell(s) - could be a problem there. Or... It looks like you are changing the opacity of the header / navigation bar?

Comment: are you reusing the cells or staticly implemented ....

Comment: @AbdulKarim The table contains only 1 cell of this type. And the cells are dynamic, not static.

Comment: @DonMag Actually the tableview contains other type of cells also. The only one that is creating the jerk is this one. I too couldn't figure out the exact issue.

Comment: Try to "rule out" causes... Temporarily replace complex cells with simple cells, and see if the "jerk" goes away. At some point, you *should* find the culprit.